# Identifying parameters of parameter server

Tags: machine-learning, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I'm currently working on large scale machine learning solvers. Then I came across with this '**Parameter Server**' concept, and I have a basic idea how it's work. So what could be the possible parameters for parameter server? (Suppose I'm going to implement one, then what parameters should I be concerned with?)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the parameter server is a distributed architecture allowing to updating the model's parameters during the training process. Hence, the parameter here refers to the weights and biases.